# Equivalence in two definition of free modules

Tags: modules, free-modules

I am currently reading Dummit & Foote and i get confused when encountered with two definitions of free modules. One which i read on wikipedia says that 
"A [free module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_module) is a module with a basis"

The second one which i read in book says  " An R module F is said to be free on a subset A of F if for all $x\neq 0$ there exists unique nonzero elements $r_{1},r_{2}, ...r_{n}$ of R and unique $a_{1},a_{2}, ...a_{n}$ in A such that $x=r_{1}a_{1}+...+r_{n}a_{n}$ for some n in positive integers.

How can we say two definitions are equivalent?
For second definition imply one we need to show for any finite subset $a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{n}$ of A, $r_{1}a_{1}+...+r_{n}a_{n}=0$ implies each $r_{i}$ is zero. But second definition only talk about nonzero elements of F.
Please provide me a hint or tell me is there anything wrong assumed in definition second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second definition $\rightarrow$ The first definition.

We have to show that $F$ has a basis $A$, i.e. for any finite subset $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ of $A$, $r_1a_1+...+r_na_n=0$ implies each $r_i$ is zero. Suppose there is some $r_i \not=0$ (without loss of generality, $r_1 \not =0$), then $$r_1a_1=-r_2a_2- \cdots -r_na_n,$$ 
which means the element $r_1a_1$ has two expressions, contradict to the second definition. Hence $r_1=0$. Similarly, each $r_i$ is zero.

The first defintion $\rightarrow$ The second definition

I think you can prove it.

Comment: I have a little confusion in your explanation that are we sure $r_{1}a_{1} \neq 0$ because in definition 2 we said only nonzero elements has unique expression !!

Comment: @Vaibhav Kalia If $r_1a_1 \not=0$, then we get two expressions of $r_1a_1$, contradiction. Hence $r_1a_1=0$ and $r_1=0$.

Comment: @Xiason Peng When $r_{1}a_{1} \neq 0$ then we get contradiction hence $r_{1}a_{1}=0$ Does this imply $r_{1}=0$ ? Actually i am confused at this point only because in modules it can happen $r.a=0$ but none of r and a are zero. Please explain this.

Comment: @Vaibhav Kalia  If $ra =0$ and $r \not=0$, take any nonzero element $x$ with the unique expression $x=r_1a_1+ \cdots + r_na_n$, then $x+0=x$ and we get another expression of $x$: $x=ra+r_1a_1+ \cdots + r_na_n$, contradiction.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @ Xiaosong Peng.